# how to get "params" in a client component in Next13?

Tags: next.js, parameters

I know that we can get query parameters i-e  **(/home?id=1)** via the **`useSearchParams`** hook, I want to get /home/[id] in a client component, as before we were using the `next/router`  **router.query**, but in next/navigation that is no longer supported.

In a server component, I can get them by using the prop `param`  but how do I get them in a client component?

I tried using the router.query but that is longer supported in the next13 directory and has to use the next/navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there will be a `useParams` hook in the future, but for the time being the section on the [beta docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs) seems to be grayed out.

So you've got two options:

Pass the `params` down from the server component to the child client component:

```js
// app/page.js
export default function Page({ params }) {
  return (
    <ClientComponent params={params} />
  )
}

// app/ClientComponent.js
"use client"

export default function ClientComponent({ params }) {
  // use `params` here
}
```

Or use some of the other hooks like `usePathname` or `useSelectedLayoutSegment` to extract the id from the url. For example, if your dynamic url is `/home/[id]`, `usePathname` will return `/home/1` if the url is `/home/1`, so you can strip the `/home/` part to get the id.

Comment: Thanks for the responses,  We can get them in a client component but I was hoping for a way to get them directly in a server component without using a client child component.

Comment: You don't have to use a client child component either. If you remove "use client" from the ClientComponent above, it would function as a server component that receives the `params` prop from the parent.

Comment: Btw your comment is different from your original question: 'how to get "params" in a client component'. But in your comment you're talking about getting the `params` directly in a server component. Can you maybe clarify what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to get them in a client component directly not the server ( I mixed it in my previous comment), as for getting the params I actually need the component to be a client component not a server component so I can't get the params to prop, also the reason I was hoping for a way to get them directly in a client component was to avoid prop drilling from parent > child > child > child if needed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @WaqasKhan. In that case, I'd probably go with `usePathname` for the time being, until `useParams` is implemented

Comment: Well, I guess for now I'll have to go with either passing the params to a child or the pathname, thanks.

Comment: To anyone new coming to this conversation, the `useParam` hook is now available in Next13 latest version, so you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Waqas Khan said in a comment above

> To anyone new coming to this conversation, the useParam hook is now available in Next13 latest version, so you can use that.

I too updated NextJS and associated libraries and the `{params}` prop as well as `useParam` function both work in client components.

Link to the post where I first noted the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218124/7353382