# Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'params' as it is undefined in Next.js 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get the [id] URL param in Next.js 13.4 but I'm getting an error saying that `params` is undefined.

I have been searching on theinternet and asking to ChatGPT but all I find is the Next.js old versions code, not Next.js 13.2+ with the new features.

I have this code example from another project and it works perfectly:

```
import Link from "next/link";

const fetchPost = (id) => {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 60 },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
};

export default async function Post({ children, params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const post = await fetchPost(id);
  return (
    <article>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
      <Link href={`/posts/${id}/comments`}>View comments</Link>
      {children}
    </article>
  );
}
```

But when I try to adapt it to my code, it doesn't work.

This is my original code: (the endpoint es working properly)

```
import styles from "./Post.module.css";

async function fetchPostById(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${id}`);
  const post = await response.json();
  return post;
}

export default async function Post({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const postById = await fetchPostById(id);
  console.log("Params: " + params);
  return (
    <>
      <li className={styles.li} key={postById.id}>
        <p className={styles.a}>
          <h3>{postById.title}</h3>
          <p>{postById.body}</p>
        </p>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have this configuration:

```
{
  "name": "demo-paco",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.8"
  }
}
```

I get this error:

`- error app\posts\[id]\Post.jsx (10:10) @ id`

`- error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'params' as it is undefined. at Post (./app/posts/[id]/Post.jsx:17:13) at stringify (<anonymous>)`

I managed to make it work, but in the line `const params = useParams();` I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

Updated code:

```
"use client";

import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import styles from "./Post.module.css";

async function fetchPostById(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${id}`);
  const post = await response.json();
  return post;
}

export default async function Post() {
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.id;
  const postById = await fetchPostById(id);
  return (
    <>
      <li className={styles.li} key={postById.id}>
        <p className={styles.a}>
          <h3>{postById.title}</h3>
          <p>{postById.body}</p>
        </p>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

Updated code for GLHF:

`page.jsx` inside of `/app/posts/[id]`:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import PostById from "./PostById";
import CommentsByPostId from "./CommentsByPostId";

export default async function PostPage({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  return (
    <section className="main">
      <Link className="goBack" href={"/posts"}>
        Go back
      </Link>
      <h1>Post:</h1>
      <PostById id={id} />
      <h1>Comments:</h1>
      <CommentsByPostId id={id} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

`PostById.jsx` inside of `/app/posts/[id]`:

```
import styles from "./PostById.module.css";

async function fetchPost(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${id}`);
  const courses = await response.json();
  return courses;
}

export default async function PostById({ id }) {
  const post = await fetchPost(id);
  return (
    <article>
      {
        <li className={styles.li} key={post.id}>
          <h3 className={styles.colorBlack}>{post.title}</h3>
          <p className={styles.colorBlack}>{post.body}</p>
        </li>
      }
    </article>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to import `usePrams` first and then declare `const params = useParams();`   - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params

Comment: @the.marolie I managed to make it work, but in the line ```const params = useParams();``` I get this error: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')```.

Comment: Can you update the question  with the latest code and notes please

Comment: Do you found any solution? Suddenly I've started to get the same error

Comment: @GLHF Yeah, I fixed it, but now I don't remember exactly how hahaha. But I think I coded the params in the page.jsx, not inside of the PostById component. I'm gonna edit the answer to you can show those 2 files

Comment: I had an route.ts file in a directory like /api/path1 but the route.ts file expected a param called 'hash'. So the route would work if it resided in i.e. /api/path1/[hash]

But apparently it didn't, which in my case, rendered the error `Cannot destructure property 'hash' of 'context.params' as it is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work for me after removing the async from the functional component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the `{params}` prop to work on my client component after updating NextJS and related libraries with this command

```
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest
```

As outlined here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-13

Got this idea from some of the comments in the NextJS Github repo such as this one: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43577#discussioncomment-7153856