# nextjs sanity TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'param' as it is undefined. when using 'use client' directive on server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, sanity

I am new to `Next.js`, and I'm building an e-commerce site using `Next.js` and `Sanity`. I have a `getProducts` function that fetches product details from Sanity. In the `ProductPage`,I import the `getProducts` function, and it runs on the client server and works fine.

However, I want to use React hooks in this code. When I use the use client directive, it throws an error:

```bash
'TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'param' as it is undefined.'
```

If I use the use client directive, do I need to use `useEffect` to fetch the products using the `getProducts` function? What might be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

here is my code that fetches data from sanity

```js
export async function getProducts(slug) {
  const client = createClient({
    projectId: 'mjkpoclj',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2023-06-18',
  })

  const product = await client.fetch(
    groq`*[_type == 'product' && slug.current == $slug]{
      _id,
      _createdAt,
      name,
      details,
      price,
      "slug": slug.current,
      images[] {
        alt,
        'url': asset->url
      },
      url,
      content
    }`,
    {slug}
  )

  return product
}
```

here is my productpage that displays product details

```
'use client'

import { getProducts } from '@/sanity/getProduct'
import { Product } from '@/app/components'

const ProductPage = async ({ params}) => {
  
  const slug = params.product

  const products = await getProducts(slug)


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center md:flex-row md:justify-around'>
          <div className='flex flex-col'>
            <div className='flex flex-col'>
              {products.length > 0 &&
                products[0].images &&
                products[0].images.length > 0 && (
                  <img
                    src={products[0].images[0].url}
                    height={300}
                    width={300}
                  />
                )}
              <h2>{products.name}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className='flex flex-row'>
              {products.map((product) => (
                <div key={product._id} className='flex flex-row'>
                  {product.images &&
                    product.images.map((image) => (
                      <>
                        <img
                          key={image.url}
                          src={image.url}
                          alt={image.alt}
                          height={70}
                          width={70}
                          // onMouseOver={index}
                        />
                      </>
                    ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className='flex flex-col'>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <>
                <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                <div className='reviews'>
                  <AiFillStar />
                  <AiFillStar />
                  <AiFillStar />
                  <AiFillStar />
                </div>
                <h4>Details:</h4>
                <h3>{product.details}</h3>
                <p className='price'> ${product.price}</p>

                <div className='quantity-box border max-w-[100px] border-gray-300 rounded flex items-center'>
                  <button className='minus-icon border-r-2 bg-transparent text-lg px-2 py-2'>
                    <AiOutlineMinus />
                  </button>

                  <span className='quantity px-2'>4</span>

                  <button className='plus-icon border-l-2 bg-transparent text-lg px-2 py-2'>
                    <AiOutlinePlus />
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className='buttons'>
                  <button type='button' className='add-to-cart'>
                    Add to Cart
                  </button>

                  <button type='button' className='buy-now'>
                    Buy Now
                  </button>
                </div>
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='maylike-products-wrapper'>
          <h2>You may also like</h2>
          <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
            <div className=''>
              <Product />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductPage
```

I wanted to fetch data from sanity and pass slug and display products on ProductPage

Comment: I got my `{params}` prop to work in a client component by updating NextJS and related libraries. A few more details can be found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218124/7353382

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it looks like you'll need to use the [`useParams` hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params) here since it's a client component. You can only use the [`params` prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#params-optional) in server components.